# Can DISTINCT mysqli queries be ordered?

Tags: mysql

I query my database with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type FROM drinks ORDER BY order ASC
```

And I get this error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order ASC' at line 1
```

It's definitely the ORDER BY order ASC that's breaking it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
SELECT DISTINCT type FROM drinks ORDER BY `order` ASC
```

You can use this too

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.type FROM drinks AS d ORDER BY d.order ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Mysql is getting confused by the fact that your column is called 'order' because 'order' is a keyword in mysql. Adding the backticks (as in the other answer) will make sure that mysql realises that it's meant to be a column-name.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for explaining what's going on here :)